# Rank dates in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api, rank

How can I rank dates on Tableau?

By customer, I have a list of codes banked (every code has an ID and an issue day) and I am interested in calculating the number of days between the first banked code and (as exemple) the 10th code (the difference will be calculated on the issue days).

Some people may have 1 code, some 2, some 10, some 100, etc. I'm only interested in calculating this metric when the number of codes banked is > 9.

The result will be, by customer, Code 10 Issue Date - Code 1 Issue Date.
So I expect that most engaged customers will bank 10 codes in 10 days, less engaged customers will bank 10 in more days.

EDIT: added below an example of the data source (first three columns) and the missing fields to be calculated (last two columns)

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a sample of the source data you are using in a table format.

Comment: Does is always need to be the 10th code? Or are you looking for the difference between the first code and the last code?

Comment: Hi Sam M, no the last one would have been the easiest calculation. I need to find a predetermined position. It could be 10, 20, etc. In some cases it will be also the last one (people who have banked 10 codes), in some cases users won't have 10 (or any other number) codes banked.

Comment: Hi tyvich, I added the example as per your request, thanks!